# Can I turn candidates dataset to input on retrieval topK tensorflow model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have a retrieval tensorflow training model and i use a `tfrs.layers.factorized_top_k.BruteForce` to get a prediction of firsts k's nearby candidates as implemented below:

```
index = tfrs.layers.factorized_top_k.BruteForce(final_model.query_model)

index.index_from_dataset(
    tf.data.Dataset.zip((parsed_topK.batch(128).map(lambda x: x['id']), parsed_topK.batch(128).map(final_model.candidate_model)))
)
```

and get the top 5 results:

```
results = index(input_query, k=5)
```

I want to know if is possible to turn the search database, represented in this code by `parsed_topK`, in to an input to the model, something like:

```
index(input_query, input_candidates, k=5)
```

where `input_candidates = parsed_topK` in this example

I have tryed to call `final_model.predict(input_query, input_candidates)`, but i need to implement a call() method and i dont know what this method need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do that creating a custom brute force class modifying the `Bruteforce` original class:

```
@tf.keras.saving.register_keras_serializable(package="MyLayers")
class BruteForce2(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  """Brute force retrieval."""

  def __init__(self, model, k=5, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.model = model
        self.k = k
        self._k = k
        
  def _compute_score(self, queries: tf.Tensor,
                     candidates: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
    
        return tf.matmul(queries, candidates, transpose_b=True)

  
  # @tf.function
  def call(self, queries: tf.Tensor, candidates_raw: tf.data.Dataset, k):
    
    candidates = tf.data.Dataset.zip(candidates_raw.map(lambda x: 
x['id']), 
                                           
candidates_raw.map(final_model.candidate_model)
                                          )
    
    spec = candidates.element_spec

    if isinstance(spec, tuple):
      identifiers_and_candidates = list(candidates)
      candidates = tf.concat(
          [embeddings for _, embeddings in identifiers_and_candidates],
          axis=0
      )
      identifiers = tf.concat(
          [identifiers for identifiers, _ in identifiers_and_candidates],
          axis=0
      )
    else:
      candidates = tf.concat(list(candidates), axis=0)
      identifiers = None
    
    self._candidates = candidates

    if identifiers is None:
      identifiers = tf.range(candidates.shape[0])
    if tf.rank(candidates) != 2:
      raise ValueError(
          f"The candidates tensor must be 2D (got {candidates.shape}).")
    if candidates.shape[0] != identifiers.shape[0]:
      raise ValueError(
          "The candidates and identifiers tensors must have the same 
number of rows "
          f"(got {candidates.shape[0]} candidates rows and 
{identifiers.shape[0]} "
          "identifier rows). "
      )
    # We need any value that has the correct dtype.
    identifiers_initial_value = tf.zeros((), dtype=identifiers.dtype)
    self._identifiers = self.add_weight(
        name="identifiers",
        dtype=identifiers.dtype,
        shape=identifiers.shape,
        initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(
            value=identifiers_initial_value),
        trainable=False)
    self._candidates = self.add_weight(
        name="candidates",
        dtype=candidates.dtype,
        shape=candidates.shape,
        initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros(),
        trainable=False)
    self._identifiers.assign(identifiers)
    self._candidates.assign(candidates)
    # self._reset_tf_function_cache()
    

    k = k if k is not None else self._k

    if self._candidates is None:
      raise ValueError("The `index` method must be called first to "
                       "create the retrieval index.")

    if self.model.query_model is not None:
      queries = self.model.query_model(queries)

    scores = self._compute_score(queries, self._candidates)

    values, indices = tf.math.top_k(scores, k=k)

    return values, tf.gather(self._identifiers, indices)
```